# Access to XAML Live Preview in .Net MAUI

Tags: visual-studio, maui, preview

I learned that a XAML Live Preview is available for .Net MAUI. But I feel like I don't have access to it.

I've tried to follow a tutorial which explain that I have to go to **Debug > Windows > XAML Live Preview** but I didn't find the functionnality.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uaze9.png)

Is there an extension I need to download to use it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official document said:

> The XAML Live Preview window is available during debugging. To open it, go to Debug > Windows > XAML Live Preview.

So it can only be accessed when you debug your project. You need to run your project in the debug mode at first.

And then, you can **go to Debug > Windows > XAML Live Preview**. For more information, you can read the official document about the
[XAML Live Preview window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-live-preview?view=vs-2022#xaml-live-preview-window).